# Is barring Holy O's in "Irredeemable" a Mark Waid thing, Boom Studios thing, or something else?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, religion, production, boom-studios

Reading *Irredeemable*, my first Boom Studios comic, and I've noticed in a few issues that when divine words are used — God, Lord, etc. — the O is barred. Take a look at page 1 of issue 17, first panel:

[image: Irredeemable 17, Page 01, Panel 01. View of a twon in ruins, captioned "Talwart, Iowa. Post-Plutonian population:612." Two unattached text balloons reading "Plutonian--Tony-- came through here not long after he went berserk. Lørd knows why..." and "...but I rather have my doubts that Gød cares."]

I'm basically just curious: is this a reflection of the faith of one of the creators (Mark Waid, or possibly letterer Ed Dukeshire), something Boom does across the board, or something else specific to the comic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On his "[Thrillbent](http://thrillbent.com/)" online comic website, [Mark Waid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Waid) has several webcomics that include the word God without the characteristic 'crossing' above;

[image: Mark Waid Webcomic You're So Smart]
[image: Mark Waid Webcomic Luther]

Ed Dukeshire, Boom Comics and Mark Waid were all involved in the creation of "[Incorruptible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incorruptible)" which has repeated uses of the word God and Lord with no 'crossing'

[image: Mark Waid Comic Incorruptible Issue #18]

Also, in later issues of "[Irredeemable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irredeemable)", the word God is regularly used without 'crossing'

[image: Irredeemable Issue #32 Screenshots]

Since the only place this styling is used is when we hear **the "inner monologue" of [Qubit](http://www.comicvine.com/qubit/4005-68033/),** I think we can safely assume that this is intended to subtly show his utter devotion to Christianity.

Comment: It's been a while since I read the series. Was Qubit established as Christian? It might as readily just be a personal quirk.